# What is the difference between setting properties to the global object and the window object?

Tags: javascript

```
this.f = function() {};
window.d = function() {};

d();
f();
```

Any difference?

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if it's run barely (e.g. not within special functions etc.). Because then `this === window`.

In constructor functions etc. `this` has another meaning, so then it matters:

```
function x() {
    this.a = 123;
}
```

Now,

- `x()` would set `window.a` to `123`
- `var test = new x()` would set `test.a` to `123`.